# How to fill an array with a value using void generic pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, generics, casting

Given the following method

```
void fillArray(void *arr, int const numElements, void *val, int size)
```

How can you fill an array (`*arr`) with a value (`*val`) without knowing what type the array ? `numElements` is the number of elements that are in the array and size is the byte size of whatever type the array is.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `memcpy` for that. However, in order to advance the memory location, you have to cast input pointer to a `char*` first. If you have `void*`, the pointer arithmetic operations are not defined.

```
void fillArray(void *arr, int const numElements, void *val, int size)
{
   char* cp = arr;
   int i = 0;
   for ( ; i < numElements; ++i, cp += size )
   {
      memcpy(cp, val, size);
   }
}
```

Comment: I see, I had misunderstood the question.