# How to scan values into an array using a generic void pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, generics, scanf

Given the method header

```
void scanArray(void *arr, int const numElements, int const sizeElement, char const *fmt)
```

where `*arr` can be any type of `array`, `numElements` is the number of elements in the array, and `sizeElement` is the size of the type of value in the array, and `fmt` is a string such as `%d`, `%lf`, or `%f`, how would you write a function that uses `scanf` to insert values into the array?

Comment: Let us know what you have tried.  How far did you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fill an array with a value using void generic pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22872419/how-to-fill-an-array-with-a-value-using-void-generic-pointers)

Comment: not supposed to be a duplicate since the user specifies the individual values that are inserted into the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void scanArray(void *arr, int const numElements, int const sizeElement, char const *fmt){
  int i;
  unsigned char *tempArr = (unsigned char*) arr;
  for(i=0; i<numElements; i++, tempArr+=sizeElement) scanf(fmt, tempArr);
}
```

This seems to be working for me...

Comment: I guess I have two questions: How is the value that scanf returns assigned to the *arr (tempArr)? Also, what is the difference between an unsigned char and a signed char, i.e. why do you have to cast it to an unsigned char?

Comment: scanf reads some bytes from stding according to the string given as the 1st argument, and saves it at the address pointed by tempArr (which is incremented btw each time an input is processed).
The input string gives additional information about the bytes the input takes, and then it is saved (without checking if the space allocated is enough) to the pointed address. That's why scanf isn't the safest of methods...

Comment: As for char vs unsigned char, when working with raw bytes, always prefer unsigned char. A char is a signed value, which means that it takes values from -128 to 127, or something like that. An unsigned char gets values from 0 ~ 255. That's because a char or an unsigned char only takes 1 byte (8 bits) of space in memory.
Which is 2^8 different values. In fact, when working with bytes that doesn't have any real difference. Because all you have is ones and zeros. But, for example 11111111(binary) value as a signed is -128(dec), but as an unsigned it is 255(dec).

Comment: This is undefined behaviour, although likely to work on common systems. But don't do it in production code.  (The cast to `unsigned char *` allows arithmetic to be done on the pointer; it's not legal to write `arr += sizeElement`).

Comment: @Frustrated Soul BTW: `char` is signed on some systems (IMO - more common) and unsigned on others.  C allows either.